# Import huge data by partitioning with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, parallel-processing, etl

I have a huge table in an OLTP DB with about 20M new rows a day.
I would like to import data from this table and be as close to real-time as possible.
I would like to create some logical partitioning on the table and import them using several DFT in an SSIS package. I think these DFTs should run in parallel so that I can use as many resources as possible.
I tried looking on the web for an article or a similar case study but couldn't find. 
Maybe I missed it is worst I am in the wrong direction and no one uses this solution to import data in such a scenario.
what would you do? If you think my solution can be a good one how should I create the partitions? On a key? Date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should think about to  share processing between SSIS and DB Engine. So use SSIS for just ETL process, create multiple tables on SQL Server and only redirect data from your packages. For rest of part i.e. combining data from all the tables and creating partitions you can then harness power of SQL Server. In some scenario, SSIS is really resource intensive but same  can be achieved(if possible) by DB Engine with less resources.

Also sometime it depends on which source/destination component you are using. [This](http://gqbi.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/ssis-fastest-data-flow-task-item-for-transferring-data-over-the-network/) is really nice article where author has done some test by setting some benchmarks on different kind of sources and destinations.

Below are the few resources, you can have a quick look to get idea.

- [MSDN - We Loaded 1TB in 30 Minutes with SSIS, and So Can You](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537533%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
- [Speeding Up SSIS Bulk Inserts into SQL Server](http://henkvandervalk.com/speeding-up-ssis-bulk-inserts-into-sql-server)
- [Speeding up Reading from a SQL OLE DB or ADO.Net Data Source](http://henkvandervalk.com/speeding-up-reading-from-a-sql-ole-db-or-ado-net-data-source)
- [Reading as fast as possible from a table with SSIS](http://henkvandervalk.com/reading-as-fast-as-possible-from-a-table-with-ssis-part-ii)
- [Top 10 Methods to Improve ETL Performance](http://www.developer.com/db/top-10-methods-to-improve-etl-performance-using-ssis.html)
- [MSDN - Data Flow Performance Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141031.aspx)
- [8 Ways to Optimize and Improve Performance of your SSIS Package](http://thinknook.com/8-ways-to-optimize-your-ssis-package-2013-06-28/)
- [The SSIS tuning tip that everyone misses](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/02/17/the-ssis-tuning-tip-that-everyone-misses.aspx)
- [SSIS – Non-blocking, Semi-blocking and Fully-blocking components](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2008/02/12/ssis-lookup-transformation-is-case-sensitive.aspx)
- [SSIS blocking, non blocking, and partially blocking transformations](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/Daniel/ssas/1361/ssis-blocking-non-blocking-and-partially-blocking-transformations)
- [FASTEST DATA FLOW TASK ITEM FOR TRANSFERRING DATA](http://gqbi.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/ssis-fastest-data-flow-task-item-for-transferring-data-over-the-network/)

Comment: Thank you. Any thoughts on how to do so in sql?